# Login to Remote Site and Exporting XML with PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to log into [IPS Light](https://ipslight.upu.org) and exporting a XML file. The url of the export page is unique and cannot be directly referenced in the script; Meaning that I will be required to click the necessary links on the homepage that will redirect me to the XML Export page.

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . "/configuration.php" );

$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$dir = site_path."/ctemp";
$path = site_path."/ctemp/test";

$url="https://ipslight.upu.org/"; 
$postinfo = "email=".$username."&password=".$password;

$cookie_file_path = $path."/cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://ipslight.upu.org/IPSLight.dll");
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Sounds good.  Let us know how we can help.